# Ender 3 Pro firmware upgrade fails

Tags: creality-ender-3, bltouch

Problem with Creality v1.1.4 (Ender 3 Pro) and BLTouch (Creality V1 mainboard - upgraded version).

Error when attempting the firmware upgrade.

After downloading and executing `progisp.exe`, I get the error message shown below:

[image]